# convert the numeric string to integer value

Tags: c

I was trying to convert the string of numbers into integer value with the following code. The output is always one less than the original value. I am not getting what's wrong with my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){

    char a[6];

    int i,b;

    scanf("%s",a);

    for(i=strlen(a)-1;i>=0;i--){

        a[i]=a[i]-48;

        b=b+a[i]*pow(10,(strlen(a)-i-1));
    }

    printf("%d",b);

    getch();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is the assignment to do the conversion yourself? Otherwise use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol). Also don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by `48` you mean the character `'0'` then say so explicitly.

Comment: As for your problem, there's no need to use `pow` here, just a simple multiplication with `10`.

Comment: Besides the indeterminate `b` value, shall we also assume negative values aren't an option, nor any value larger than 99999?

Comment: You are scanning the string from right to left, but there is an easier way.  Initialize your variable `b` to 0. Start at the *left* of the string.  For each digit that you see, multiply `b` by 10 and add in the digit.  When you stop seeing digits, you're done.  That way you don't even have to call `strlen`.

Comment: You are overwriting your string and using `strlen` on the modified string. If there is '0' in your string, then `strlen` will return a different value than originally.

Comment: setting the bounds and initializing the variable b don't solve the problem. the problem is with pow() function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in your code. For reducing risks of **UB**:

1. If you treat `char[]` as string, its size should allow for accommodating the `\0` terminating character.
2. If your code doesn't initialize non-static local variable values, you should do it explicitly (variable `int b`).
3. Treat `scanf()` cautiously if you read a string. Overflow leads to UB. Use a field width specifier.
4. Don't mix data types (return of `pow()` is `double`).
5. Make your code as lean as possible, with as little math as practical, especially inside loops. You don't need `pow()` altogether.

Please, see the comments along the lines based on your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[7];      // extra byte for '\0'
    int i, l, b = 0;//initialize local variable b
    int ten = 1;

    scanf("%6s",a); //should use a field width specifier

    l = strlen(a) - 1;

    for( i=l ; i>=0 ; i--, ten*=10 )
        b += (a[i]-48)*ten; //do as simple math as practical

    printf("%d\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely *undefined behavior* because you use uninitialized variables.

In the expression `b=b+...` you use the variable `b` without initializing it first. Non-static local variables are not initialized and will have an *indeterminate* value. Using them without initialization leads to UB. Initialize it to zero:

```
int i, b = 0;
```

You also have problems with the user entering to many characters for the array `a` and going out of bounds. You also don't have any checks that the user actually only entered digits.

Comment: even if i initialize the variable b the output is still 1 less than the original value but if i don't use the pow() function , i get the desired output. but what is wrong with the pow() function?

Comment: @shivam The [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) function is for *floating point*, with all the rounding problems that come with it.

Comment: @shivam It's likely that, for example, `pow(10, 3)` is giving you 999.999 instead of 1000.  (Or maybe  `pow(10, 0)` is giving you 0.999 instead of 1.0, or `pow(10, 1)` is giving you 9.999 instead of 10.)